# Why won't my geometry nodes stick to my mesh?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

Trying to use a collection to make different sizes of bubbles on my mesh.
It gets placed on the side of my mesh instead of on it.
However, when I also click "reset children", it places them correctly on the mesh, but only gives me one bubble instead of the three different sized ones. Why?
[image]
[image]

Comment: pls provide your blend file....sounds weird. the "distance" to your object is ok if you don't click "reset" children then the local location of the objects will be taken into account btw if you only want different size of your instance, you can do it like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr3EH.png

Comment: Check 'Relative' in your _Object Info_ node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't apply the scale on your original bubbles, the scale will be reset as well, when activating *reset children*.

Thus, apply scale on your orignal bubbles and it should work, when activating *reset children*.